# DocumentDB subdocument projection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I created an collection with this kind of document:

```
{       
    "Date": 1481673600,
    "Name": "Test"
    "DailyCurve": [
      {
        "TimeStamp": 1481673600,
        "ACPower": 0,        
        "DCPower": 0
      },
      {
        "TimeStamp": 1481716800,
        "ACPower": 30.599999999999998,
        "DCPower": 0
      },
      {
        "TimeStamp": 1481717700,
        "ACPower": 50.099999999999994,
        "DCPower": 0
      },
      {
        "TimeStamp": 1481718600,
        "ACPower": 46.6,
        "DCPower": 0
      },
    ]
}
```

Because I want to query a huge amount of data I want to use projection to reduce the RUs needed.

I understand for example if I only need the `Date` value I simply use this query:

```
SELECT c.Date FROM c
```

But now I also want to project the sub documents under `DailyCurve` property.

To receive the full set I can use:

```
SELECT c.Date, c.DailyCurve FROM c
```

But what do I have to do to only receive the `TimeStamp` and `ACPower` values?

The result I want to create should look like this:

```
[{      
    "Date": 1481673600,
    "DailyCurve": [
      {
        "TimeStamp": 1481673600,
        "ACPower": 0,
      },
      {
        "TimeStamp": 1481716800,
        "ACPower": 30.599999999999998,
      },
      {
        "TimeStamp": 1481717700,
        "ACPower": 50.099999999999994,
      },
      {
        "TimeStamp": 1481718600,
        "ACPower": 46.6,
      },
    ]
},
...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need user-defined functions to do this. First, register a UDF for project like this one:

```
function project(document) {
  var result = {};
  result["Date"] = document["Date"];
  result["DailyCurve"] = [];

  var dailyCurve = document["DailyCurve"]; 
  for (var idx in dailyCurve) {
    var elem = dailyCurve[idx];
    result["DailyCurve"].push(
       { "TimeStamp": elem["TimeStamp"], 
         "ACPower": elem["ACPower"]});
  }  
  return result;
}
```

Then use it in a DocumentDB query like:

```
SELECT udf.project(c) FROM c
```

If you'd like to see native support for sub-query projections in DocumentDB (without need for UDFs), please propose/upvote here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb

Comment: Thank you Aravind from Microsoft :) I create a propose https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/17762254-native-support-for-sub-query-projections